# How to manage 3 ways of filtering in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

This is an architectural and implementation question, but I'm more focused on getting ideas for big picture strategy.

### The scenario

The app lists `Foo` records in a table.  There are several ways to sort them as follows:

- By attribute `b_domains`, each `Foo` `has_many :b_domains, :through => :b_domain_foos`

  - Easy enough, simply get all `foos` by `b_domains`, this is working.
- By a set of drop-down pills.  `Foos` `belong_to` each of the objects represented by a pill.  For example, a `foo` may belong to an instance of `M` called `m_one`.

  - Each `foo` should be able to be sorted with any number of pills of type `M`, `N`, `O`, or `P`.
- Freeform text search.
- All of this should be done with js and never reload the page.

What are some strategies to keep the active list of `foos` in memory?  Is this a common Rails pattern?  Where can I find an example?

What I find myself beginning to do is completely replace the list of `foos` rather than refining the list in memory on new requests.

Thanks.

Comment: What is "the active list of foos"?  Rails is generally "stateless", in that each request starts from scratch.  However you do have various tools like caching which can save you from doing all the work every time.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, I guess I'm missing the idea of statelessness.  I am referring to how to manage the results of the two filters that are not sending requests to the server.